# ion-split-page not showing side menu options in desktop mode while working in mobile mode

Tags: ionic-framework

with ion-split-page added, I am not able to see my side menu options which are displaying properly in mobile view.

`

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main">
    <!--  the side menu  -->
    <ion-menu side="start" menuId="m1" contentId="main">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Wanderlust</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle menu="m1">
            <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/places/tabs/discover">
              <ion-icon name="business" slot="start"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Discover Places</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-menu-toggle menu="m1">
            <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/bookings">
              <ion-icon name="checkbox-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Your Bookings</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-menu-toggle menu="m1">
            <ion-item lines="none" (click)="onLogout()" button>
              <ion-icon name="exit" slot="start"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Logout</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <!-- the main content -->
    <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

`
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add  autoHide="false" attribute on ion-menu-toggle.

`<ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false">`